# WPF C# LINQ: Assigning a different value for a field in the retrieved query

Tags: c#, sql, wpf, linq

I'm trying to to assign a value to the "trades.Price_5s" field after the query has executed. Here's the code:

```
var TradeStatsQuery = (from trades in connection.TradeStatsDatas
                               where (trades.Price_5s == null) || (trades.Price_10s == null)
                               || (trades.Price_30s == null) || (trades.Price_60s == null)
                               || (trades.Price_5min == null) || (trades.Price_15min == null)
                               || (trades.Price_30min == null) || (trades.Price_60min == null)
                               select new
                               {
                                   trades.TradeID,
                                   trades.CurrencyPair,
                                   trades.Action,
                                   trades.ExecutedDateTime,
                                   trades.Price_5s,
                                   trades.Price_10s,
                                   trades.Price_30s,
                                   trades.Price_60s,
                                   trades.Price_5min,
                                   trades.Price_15min,
                                   trades.Price_30min,
                                   trades.Price_60min
                               });


        if(TradeStatsQuery.Count() > 0)
        {
            foreach(var id in TradeStatsQuery)
            {
                if(id.Price_5s == null)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("-----------------------------------------");
                    Console.WriteLine("Trade ID: " + id.TradeID);

                    DateTime ET_plus5s = id.ExecutedDateTime.AddSeconds(5);

                    if(DateTime.Now >= ET_plus5s)
                    {
                        decimal retrieved_5sPrice;
                        Console.WriteLine("Fetching 5 second past trade price...");
                        retrieved_5sPrice = tb_connection.GetCurrencyRate(id.CurrencyPair, id.Action, ET_plus5s);
                        Console.WriteLine("Price 5 sec: " + retrieved_5sPrice);
                        id.Price_5s = retrieved_5sPrice;
```

I'm trying to assign the price I retrieved to the field in the query which is currently set at null, so I can later go back and overwrite all the fields I queried with their updated values. Is this possible? Can I assign a different value to a field I queried earlier? The last line is where the error occurs.

Error Message: "Property or indexer 'AnonymousType#1.Price_5s' cannot be assigned to -- it is read only"

Comment: Have you tried it?  And if so what happens?

Comment: Also you don't need `if(TradeStatsQuery.Count() > 0)`.  Because if nothing is returned, the collection will be empty, so the `foreach` will do nothing anyway.

Comment: Yes, the error that I get says the following "Property or indexer 'AnonymousType#1.Price_5s' cannot be assigned to -- it is read only" so I'm guessing this means I can't change it right lol There's no workaround of any sort available? @Peter M

Comment: @kknaguib Either create a new object instead of mutating it, or better yet assign the correct value from the query itself, rather than trying to mutate it later.

Comment: @kknaguib You should also edit your question and explicitly show the error message

Comment: The thing is I don't know what the value of the field is till 5 seconds after a trade is executed so this class acts as a price collector from the market but how would I create a new object and do this can you please give me an example. Thanks @Servy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your linq query you are creating anonymous types with the `new`.

As per MS [Anonymous Types (C# Programming Guide)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397696.aspx), these are read only.  Thus you can't change their values.

Comment: Ok, so how can I solve this problem using another approach. So I'm retrieving market prices after a certain time has passed, and at the end I want to load it to my database changing only the fields with null values. @Peter M

Comment: Instead of `select new {}` create a class that has those properties so and then try something like `select new MyContainer{ }`

Comment: I'm available for consulting at a decent $$ rate on a 1099 basis :D, but if not, it sounds like you have to do something like build a list of stocks that fail you 5s criteria and then re-run the linq query for them.

Comment: haha I'll give this consulting a consideration :D ok I'm gonna give this some thought see what I can come up with thanks @Peter M